# I need to CONCATENATE a letter while dividing selected cells by a constant

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, divide

I have blocks of data where some of he data in the block has a multiple of 10 applied. I need to remove the multiple of 10 and add an "A" to the same cells. There is two sets of ranges where the data lies between.

Code that was recorded

```
Sub FixShaded()
'
' FixShaded Macro

    Range("H2766").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""A""&(RC[-6]/10)"
    Range("H2766").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2766:H2770"), 
Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("H2766:H2770").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B2766").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("H2766:H2770").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Code that I am trying to get to work

```
Sub findRange()

  Dim WorkRng As Range
  Dim cell As Range
  Const CL As Long = 10
  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Set sht = ActiveSheet
  Dim i As Long
  Set WorkRng = Application.Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

   For Each cell In WorkRng
      If WorkRng > 150 And WorkRng < 1000 Then
          WorkRng.Value = WorkRng.Value / CL
      End If
      If WorkRng > 20000 And WorkRng < 250000 Then
          WorkRng.Value = WorkRng.Value / CL
      End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Sorry I am only 3 months into VBA and trying Thank you

Comment: `If WorkRng > 150` should be `If cell.Value > 150` etc for the other tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
For Each cell In WorkRng.Cells
  With cell
     If (.Value > 150 And .Value < 1000) Or _
        (.Value > 20000 And .Value < 250000) Then

             .Value = "A" & .Value / CL
     End If
  End with
Next
```